can I write a type-level function to find the element type of an array-like container?
This is basically what I want, but rustc complains about unconstrained type param T. Is there another way?
trait GetElemType {
    type ElemType;
}

impl<T, ContainerType> GetElemType for ContainerType where
    ContainerType: AsRef<[T]>,
{
    type ElemType = T;
}

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8a463291e33ed2946b3263cc10616309

The issue is that this would (in theory) cause GetElemType to be implemented many times for ContainerType for each T that satisfies the bound. What are you overall trying to accomplish?

To be even more explicit, there may be multiple T for which ContainerType implements AsRef<[T]>, yet you apparently want ContainerType to have exactly one ElemType?

If using Deref instead of AsRef is acceptable then you can do this.

Actually, for a container, using IntoIterator might be better: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f171462c2449198b49fb861aa6e88e98

@cdhowie, but the latter makes the ContainerType useless as you can just use IntoIterator::Item directly instead of using GetElemType::ElemType

Maybe you want to switch an ElemType from being an associated type to a type parameter of trait GetElemType?

@cafce25 Of course. I'm not saying it's more useful, just that it's probably in line with what OP is trying to do.
